# Django GET request not reading parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django and the Django REST Framework to code a web API, I created a view for user authentication. It has a corresponding model called "Users" which takes fields "email", "password", etc. The view also has a corresponding serializer called UserSerializer. Here is the code for the view, which is supposed to check if the provided email and password exists in my Users table.

```
class UsersView(APIView):

def get(self, request, _email=None, _password=None):
    if _email and _password:
        try:
            queryset = Users.objects.get(email=_email , password=_password)
        except Users.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'error': 'No user with the given credentials.'}, status=400)

        read_serializer = UsersSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(read_serializer.data)


    return Response({'error': 'Outside.'}, status=400)
```

The issue I am having is when I send a get request with a body that contains fields for _email and _password, their values are not interpreted, they just stay null.

For example, if I add the line `return Response({_email}, status=400)` (which simply prints the value of email) directly under the function definition (before the if statement), I get a response "null", even when I have passed in a valid value.

Another way I tested this is by removing the function parameters altogether and instead defining variables _email and _password locally within my function and giving them values which I know already exist in my User table, this successfully returns the User object which exists in the table. Therefore it seems like the value of these function parameters are not being read.

Could anyone help me with this issue? Is there something obvious that I am not seeing here?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET

try using `request.GET.get('_email')` and `request.GET.get('_password')`

Comment: You're sending a GET request with parameters in the *body* and not in the path or query parameters?

Comment: You are sending a _GET_ request with credentials? That is **very insecure**. Furthermore `Users.objects.get(email=_email , password=_password)` this will never work if you use the builtin authentication system which hashes the passwords.

Comment: Can you share the sample URL for this view ?